# Why are AJAX requests limited to same domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss, same-origin-policy

Something I find really confusing, is why are AJAX requests limited to the same domain?  What is the reasoning behind this?

I don't see any problem with requesting files from external locations, also servers making XMLHTTP requests seem to get and post to external locations fine.

Comment: It's probably so you'r password won't get sent to some bogus server...

Comment: But the website you are on would have to send your password via a script, and they theoretically already know it so that would seem pointless?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Picture this :

You come on my fabulous website www.halfnakedgirls.com. You have fun watching what looks like technical documentation on human physiology, but behind your back, some lines of JavaScript are executing some request to another domain, let's say www.yourpaypallike.com.

Requests like `http://www.yourpaypallike.com/account/transfer?to=badguy@evilwebsite.com&amount=984654` or `http://www.mymailprovider.com/mails/export?format=csv`.

Do you now see why it is forbidden ? =)

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.  Assuming the user is logged in to Paypal, then the evil website could access an external site as if they were logged ino to it.

Comment: Pretend I'm a dummy and I don't see why it's forbidden. Is the issue that the halfnakedgirls.com is able to send evil instructions to paypal using your paypal cookies, even though it's not able to read those cookies itself?  Whereas with the "site redirect" workaround, the cookie data is stripped out and paypal will not regard you as logged in?

Comment: Exactly, because you browser automatically adds the cookies to every request made. You request yourpaypallike.com, the browser send cookies of paypallike.com along the ajax request. The 'site redirect' indeed strips the cookie. The first request done to the 'middle man server' doesn't contains cookies of the end-target (youpaypallike.com), so when the middle-man server transfer the request to paypalike, no paypallike cookies.

Comment: Why can't the browser just make the request without any cookies?

Answer (score 3):

Tom, it is not "Ajax request limited". AJAX is based on JavaScript. For security reason JavaScript is prohibited access on cross domains. If you really want to do cross domain Ajax, you can do a hack.

YourPage(Ajax) ---->  YourServer ----> ExternalDomain

You can call a page in your server using Ajax, Your domain will call to external domain using server side , and get the result then return to you as Ajax response. 
Of course the request done to the ExternalDomain server will be called WITHOUT sending cookies for ExternalDomain that reside in your browser's memory. That's because the request is done by your server and not your browser.

Answer (score 1):

It's for security purposes - if a website could execute AJAX calls to any domain they wanted on the client side, it poses a serious risk.

There are ways around this though - you could have your AJAX call a PHP script on the same domain, which in turn can call a script from another domain and return it. This wouldn't be using the browser as the communication medium though, it'd be using your web server.

Comment: Thanks, I know it poses a security risk but no one has explained what this is yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information to satisfy your question:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Thanks for the link but it still doesn't give me a satisfactory reason WHY it's not permitted, it just describes it as a security concept.