# Building a Firefox extension to parse through script tags

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, xul

I am in the process of building my first Firefox extension and I've hit a wall.  I'm also not familiar with javascript, though I do know how to program.

The extension is attempting identify malicious javascript code by running all of the code that is contained within script tags through a classifier.  I have the classifier built in Python already, but I can't figure out how to identify the javascript and send it to the classifier.  What is the best way to capture everything in-between script tags, one by one, and send it to the classifier.  The log says that each item I am capturing in the array with "var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );" is of type xulelement object, but I don't know how to get the actual code.  In the for loop, I'd like to send each item in the array to the classifier.  I've included what I have so far below:

```
function extractScripts(){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
    scriptExtractor_Log( scripts.length + ' scripts were found' );
    var sLen = scripts.length
    for ( var i=0, len=sLen; i<len; ++i ){
      scriptExtractor_Log( 'script ' + i + ': ' + scripts[i]);
    }               
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really malicious code won't be found so easily. :P

Comment: Nice target you have... Why don't you start with a Hello world! tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting the script tags won't be sufficient to identify malicious scripts. Consider this typical XSS code for example:

```
<img src="this_does_not_exist" onerror="alert('Doing something evil')">
```

If you load the HTML page in the browser anyway then you can have a look at the [JavaScript Deobfuscator extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/). This extension uses the JavaScript debugger service to intercept all JavaScript code that is being compiled or executed - even if it is generated dynamically. You can find some code examples on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/JavaScript_Debugger_Service, JavaScript Deobfuscator sets `debuggerService.scriptHook` to intercept scripts being compiled (`onScriptCreated` and `onScriptDestroyed` will be called).

Answer (score 0):

Scripts are either external or inline so you need to check the src attribute of each tag. Then you can make an AJAX request to get the source code of the script. However if the script is from another domain (which it often is) you can't retreive it due to the [cross-domain policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156710/why-are-ajax-requests-limited-to-same-domain)

```
for ( var i=0, len=sLen; i<len; ++i ){
  if ( scripts[i].src ) { //check if src is defined
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest(); //create a new XHR object
    XHR.open("GET",scripts[i].src,false); // the false here makes your request synchronus
    XHR.send(); //send the request
    scripttxt = XHR.respose;
  } else {
    scripttxt = scripts[i].innerHTML;
  }
  scriptExtractor_Log( 'script ' + i + ': ' + scripttxt);

}
```

If your using python already it might just be easier to use python libraries to parse the HTML and pull out the body of  tags

Comment: Scripts are either external or inline, or something else, or loaded dynamically, or...