# ajax request from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to write a function that has a string parameter(url) and make ajax request to this url.

i tried to do it like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Jquery Basic</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent("https://www.yahoo.com");
        alert(encodedUrl);
        $('#submit1').bind('click', function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: encodedUrl,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            success: function( result ) {
              alert("s");
              alert(result);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("error");
              alert(XMLHttpRequest);
              alert(textStatus);
              alert(errorThrown); 
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a>JQuery Test Page</a><br>
    <input id="submit1" type="button" value="Submit"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

when sending the encoded url there is an error but without any detail. 
If sending the string as it is the error is:
NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://www.yahoo.com/?_=1502748918475', or any other site. 
I've tried to "play" with the parameters (contentType, async,cache, creossDomain etc) but with no success.

thanx

Comment: Uhm, firstly, you can't do an ajax request to `yahoo.com` as it doesn't return CORS headers. Secondly, you shouldn't urlencode the URL, it's for data being sent as part of the URL, i.e. the part that comes after `?`. At the end of the day, the simple answer is just ***NO!***, you can't do a synchronous request to Yahoo like that from the clientside.

Comment: Yahoo.com is not allowing cross site accessing.

Comment: Your browser will not let you do this. For example this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156710/why-are-ajax-requests-limited-to-same-domain

Comment: what you need is an (Yahoo) endpoint that would respond to your ajax which in case yahoo.com isn't ..